# Jquery - Get Button Value Dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a JS that output the button dynamically:

```
<button class='btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn' name='likebtn' value='1' type='button'>value1text</button>

<button class='btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn' name='likebtn' value='2' type='button'>value2text</button>


$('button=[name=likebtn]').click(function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I would like to get the value of the button click! But it doesn't seem to get the name of button clicked. Why? Find it strange...

Code is here...

```
$('#div').append("<button class='btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn' name='likebtn' type='button' value='"+obj.value+"'>"+"LIKE"+"</button>");
```

Comment: The only bug I see is `alert('asd'$(this).val());` should be `alert('asd'+$(this).val());`

Comment: is the event firing at all ... if not and you are adding it dynamically then you need to use live or on depending on which version of jquery you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are outputting the buttons via javascript you need to use `on` instead of `click` to bind your events.

```
$('body').on("click", "button[name=likebtn]", function (){
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Comment: Above edit should work or just using this.value as was suggested by others.

Comment: How can I change the css class of this button clicked?

Answer (score 3):

you can just use

```
$(this).val()
```

to get value

use

```
   $(this).text()
```

to get the text

if u want to append value to `asd` use

```
alert('asd'+$(this).val());
```

and use the selector as  `$('button[name=likebtn]').click(....`

Comment: Not your selector, PSR. The selector used in the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In script, you should write :

```
$('button[name="likebtn"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());//if you are trying to get value of 'value' attribute
    alert($(this).text());//if you are trying to get text between the tag
});
```

You can look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3aWVp/) to check the example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get the text of the button, if so:

```
$(this).text()
```

And remove the 'asd':

```
alert($(this).val());
```

And fix your selector:

```
$('button[name=likebtn]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` directly and remove unwanted doublequotes.

```
$('button[name=likebtn]').click(function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/gwKn3/)

You need to correct the `append` method

```
$('div').append('<button class=btn btn-mini btn-primary likebtn name=likebtn value='+ obj.value + '>LIKE</button>');
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/gwKn3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,if the button is dynamic and brought using ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".details").click(function(){

var value=$(this).attr('id');

$.post("product-viewbills-1.php",
 {
    value1:value
 },

    function(data){
        //alert(data);
       $('#shadow').html(data);
 });
       }); 

});
```

Now the above code is the j query (ajax) we are using. $.post is used instead of $.ajax
Now we will see the button used dynamically. this one is a php code

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","amazing");  //connecting to database
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM productmaster");  //taking values from table  
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //fetching the array which contains the column
    {
?>
    <input type="button" class="details" id="<?php echo $row['pmid'];?>" value="details">
<?php
    }
?>
```

Now we have made so many buttons having unique ids and same class pmid is the column of the table we have taken.

Now each button contains different ids and can be used separately.

```
<div id="shadow"></div>
<?php
    mysqli_close($con);                //closing the database
?>
```